# MATE Desktop: misbehavior: alt-tab switching across workspaces

Tags: mate-desktop

`mate-desktop 1.26.1-1`

`6.4.12-arch1-11`

**Previous/desired behavior:** alt-tab cycles through windows in workspace.

**New behavior:** alt tab cycles through windows of the the focussed application.

For example, if I have geany open and I alt-tab it will take me to the cycle of geany windows across all workspaces.

I remember this being a global option (years ago) so I suspect the config has been overwritten but I don't see anything in recent updates that I would think a culprit.